# Can't reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to reinstall Ubuntu without losing my files, but at the "Installation type" screen the "Reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" option is greyed out so I can't select it. Anyone know what causes this, and how to fix it?